# How I can extract matrixes WI and WO from gensim word2vec?

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

CBOW word2vec scheme look like this:

[image]

How I can extract matrixes WI and WO from `gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec`?
I found only these fields in gensim w2v model:

`gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.trainables.syn1neg`

and

`gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.vw.syn1neg.vectors`

Can I make an assumption that `syn1neg` is WI, and WO = `vectors` - `syn1neg`?

Why this code

```
sentences = [['car', 'tree', 'chip2'], ['chip1', 'sugar']]
model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=1, size = 5)
```

give `Word2Vec.trainables.syn1neg` matrix with zero elements only?

For 30MB dataset `Word2Vec.trainables.syn1neg` matrix also contain zero elements only, log is here:

[gensim log](https://pastebin.com/cKfxv2zz)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `w2v_model.wv.vectors` is what was formerly called "syn0", and serves as the "projection weights" which essentially map a one-hot word-encoding into *N* dimensions. In your diagram, that's *WI*.

The `w2v_model.trainables.syn1neg` is the hidden-to-output weights for negative-sampling mode, what your diagram labels *WO*.

Comment: Thanks! But why `trainables.syn1neg` contain only zero elements (I edit my question)?

Comment: I'm not sure, but lots of things don't work as one might expect with contrived toy examples, so I'd suggest turning on logging and watching for hints of anomalies, or testing with a larger dataset. (For example, in such a tiny example, every word is 20% of the total word count – highly atypical for natural language & perhaps causing all words to be dropped by the downsampling feature controlled by the `sample` parameter.)

Comment: Even for 30MB texts Word2Vec.trainables.syn1neg contain only zero elements. Maybe I wrong start training (`model = Word2Vec(sentences, min_count=2, size = 50)`)?

Comment: Enable logging, ensure output makes sense and indicates real training is happening. (Maybe there's something wrong with your corpus format or iterable.) Do the final word-vectors of the model still seem to work even with an all-zeros `syn1neg`?

Comment: I attached log into question text, word-vectors look normal.

Comment: Your logs indicate that no training is happening, as evidenced by lines like: `WARNING : train() called with an empty iterator (if not intended, be sure to provide a corpus that offers restartable iteration = an iterable).`, `EPOCH - 1 : training on 0 raw words (0 effective words) took 0.0s, 0 effective words/s`, and `WARNING : EPOCH - 1 : supplied example count (0) did not equal expected count (290278)`. This is most likely because the corpus you're supplying as `sentences` isn't a proper restartable iterable object (necessary for the multiple passes) – as the logged WARNINGs report.

Comment: The word-vectors may "look normal" if you're only glancing at them for non-zero values, but that's just because they're initialized to small random values. To really test if they've been moved by training to useful places, try to use them in a representative way – like checking that the `most_similar()` words for an origin word make sense, or some form of your ultimate purpose.

Comment: Yes, `restartable iterable object` -- solved this problem, thx!